# Hunter hits the target with probability $\frac{3}{4}.$ What is the probability that striking $4$ times he will hit exactly $2$ times.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Hunter hits the target with probability $\frac{3}{4}.$ What is the probability that striking $4$ times he will hit exactly $2$ times.

My thinking is that $\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}\times 4!$ but in this way I don't get the answer.

Comment: Hint: exactly twice means not once and not 3 times and not 4 times.

Comment: Why have you multiplied by $4!$ ?

Comment: you are almost correct, instead of $4!$, it shouldn't it be $4 \choose 2$?

Comment: @AJ thanks, stupid mistake.

Comment: It is the middle term in the binomial expansion of $(\frac34+\frac14)^4$.